# Error running pod install while building an app

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using razorpay payment plugin for my checkout. After adding its integeration in info.plist file I am unable to open my app. It is showing me an error. I am sure that the error is there after adding plugin but dont know how to resolve it. Please Help

**Tried with flutter clean but same issue again.**

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro.
```

**Code Added**

```
Razorpay razorpay = Razorpay();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
        razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
        razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
      void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
        // Do something when payment succeeds
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    OrderResultScreen(result: 'Order Sucessfull')));
      }
    
      void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    OrderResultScreen(result: 'Payment Failed. Please try again')));
        // Do something when payment fails
      }
    
      void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => OrderResultScreen(result: 'Order....')));
        // Do something when an external wallet is selected
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        razorpay.clear();
        // TODO: implement dispose
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      Map orderDetails = {
        "id": "rzp_test_86Qc8y8X0jtLa0",
        "entity": "order",
        "amount": 50000,
        "amount_paid": 0,
        "amount_due": 50000,
        "currency": "INR",
        "receipt": "rcptid_11",
        "status": "created",
        "attempts": 0,
        "notes": [],
        "created_at": 1566986570
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when you add some new integration to the plist file. Here is an easy way to resolve it. Let me know if this works for you.

Step 1- `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

Step 2- `arch -x86_64 pod install`